# Unwanted purple background with image texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

When i add a texture image to the background of the world, an unwanted purple color comes with. I don't know how to delete it (the purple color). I see it in the preview before adding the texture image from my folder. After adding the image, the preview is OK but if i render my 3d view i have always this purple color with my image. Somebody has a solution ?

(with blender 2.74)

Thanks for your help.

Matthieu

P.S : My light is not purple and it is not a duplicate. No files are missing and i don't use blender render but cycles render.
I can see my image in the preview window. My problem is : when i assigne a texture the background is a mix with purple color and my texture. I don't want this purple color !

I think it's a bug. It works great with my older version of blender (2.66a).

Comment: Sorry but it is not my issue, I use cycles render

Comment: @Matthieu can you add some screenshots to demonstrate the problem ?

Comment: Yes, If somebody can explain me how to add some screenshots

Comment: @Matthieu on windows ? or you mean in the question ?

Comment: yes in the question

Comment: when you edit your post you'll see small square ( image of mountain ) click on it it'll open a window  , choose your image (from your PC) then click upload

Comment: don't worry about the question being closed it will be opened if it's not a duplicate

Comment: did try another texture coordinates ( else than Window ) ?

Comment: In blender when you are missing a texture you get pink. Looking at your screenshots it seems like you have no image texture assigned, therefore you get the pink color. That goes both for cycles and internal.

Comment: Yes, it works with other texture coordinate

Comment: But with other coordinates the texture shape is too bad for use in my scene. It is not very bad because it is just an exercise but i will be happy to fix it before continuing my learning of blender

Comment: you can create a cube and map the wall texture properly

Comment: unfortunately the window mode is the only way to have a texture without distortion

Comment: If you can't see your image in the preview window it means it has not been assigned. http://i.imgur.com/ZTUrk94.gif

Comment: @Matthieu the distortion is because you have to apply scale  ( Ctrl+A then scale )

Comment: I can see my image in the preview window. My problem is : when i assigne a texture the bacground is a mix with purple color and my texture.

Comment: @Matthieu try to save the blend file and reload it.

Comment: do you have other objects in the scene , and please upload the blend file

Comment: you can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Same settings as well. I think it might have something to do with the Window setting. If I set the coordinates to Normal, it shows correctly, but distorted of course. I'm not sure how this is fixed yet. If you have found a way to fix this, could you post it? -James

Comment: try to unlink the HDRI and then again link it back.

Answer (score 2):

The rest of the environment outside of the window probably doesn’t have a texture on it since you’re trying to use window space for the mapping. The purple is probably being emitted from the environment dome that’s outside your camera view

Answer (score 0):

There are some textures that have to be set to non-color data, for example this ones used for bumb mapping or alpha masking. Otherwise you have purple lights or another issues when baking textures.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Particulary to show how setting any image to *Color* instead of *Non-Color Data* can cause purple color in the environment?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the World tab then go down to the Surface>Background tab, click it and in the top right corner there are Remove and Disconnect buttons.

Click Remove and your background should return to black, white or grey.

Answer (score 0):

The Background Shader does need an Envoirment Texture and not an Image Texture

purple always means missing texture, this time because the type is wrong.

the alternative would be to put it back to color.

And maybe set the vector back to default.

[image]